# How do I use two one-handed items at once?

Tags: starbound

I'm not sure how, but for some reason my character was using a flashlight in one hand an axe in the other. I'm not sure I managed this, and I also managed to switch back to only using one item without knowing how.

How can I assign a different one-handed item to each hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click the item you want to hold with your right hand and left click the item you want to hold with your left hand. Both items must be in your toolbar and they have to be 1-handed items, such as 1-handed swords, axes or flashlights. You can combine any of them freely.

Answer (score 10):

There are two center slots for each of the two mouse buttons. If you drop an item into the right-handed (red) slot and wield a one-handed item from your normal 10 numbered slots, you will wield both items. Furthermore, pressing <kbd>X</kbd> will allow you to switch to solely your blue slot, and <kbd>Z</kbd> allows you to swap the blue with red, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Before 1.0, you put items in your hotbar, left clicked one item and right clicked the other. These must both be 1-handed items. After 1.0, each slot in your hotbar has a "left" side and a "right" side. Putting 2 1-handed items in 1 slot (one on the left side, one on the right side) and then selecting that slot will result in you holding the 2 1-handed items. These can be any 1-handed items: salves, shields, food, 1-handed swords/guns/spears, but 2-handed items (blocks, some swords/guns/spears) occupy both sides of the slot. You cannot wield a 1-handed item and a 2-handed item, nor can you wield 2 2-handed items.